# find out SVN revision on Server from shell

Tags: svn

Is it possible to find out the current revision of the SVN repo from a bash script. I thought I could do that with svnversion ...

```
REV=`svnversion http://host/path/to/svn`
```

... but it only works with local working copies.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about the following:

```
svn info http://host/path/to/svn
```

svnversion is intended to do this only for working copies.

Comment: Additionally, you can use the `--xml` flag to generate a more computer-friendly output (although I'm not sure about how easy it is to manipulate XML from bash).

Comment: The output of SVN is intended for parsing via scripts etc.